Why is my first array (arrOne) being modified when I modify a 2nd array (arrTwo)?
When I enter the user inputs of "12345" and "0", I see in the first loop arrOne is being populated the way I'm expecting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  However after the 2nd loop (which populates arrTwo) when I go to print out the values of arrOne (using the 3rd loop) I see that the values are now 0, 2, 3, 4, 5.
I'm scratching my head as to how arrOne's initial value has been modified after the initial loop. Appreciate any guidance!
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Write your main here
    string inputOne = "";
    string inputTwo = "";


    cout << "Please enter two positive integers up to 20 digits long" << endl;
    cin >> inputOne;
    cin >> inputTwo;

    int arrOne[inputOne.length() - 1];
    int arrTwo[inputTwo.length() - 1];

    for(int i = 0; i< inputOne.length(); i++){
        arrOne[i] = inputOne[i] - '0';
        cout<< "arrOne[i] = " << arrOne[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< inputTwo.length(); i++){
        arrTwo[i] = inputTwo[i] - '0';
        cout<< "arrTwo[i] = " << arrTwo[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< inputOne.length(); i++){
        cout<< "arrOne[i] = " << arrOne[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

I am expecting after the population of the arrTwo array, that the arrOne array would continue to store 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

int arrOne[inputOne.length() - 1] is not standard c++. Use std::vector. I would also recommend a good c++ book

Also start using a debugger. What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

for(int i = 0; i< inputOne.length(); i++){         arrOne[i] . . . will be a buffer overrun when i is inputOne.length() - 1. (Presuming you are using a non-standard compiler extension that handles int arrOne[inputOne.length() - 1]) The same problem in your 2nd for loop potentially could be producing the symptom you are experiencing.

int array[5] has 5 elements with valid indicies 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. Not 5.

Why the -1 in the sizes of your arrays? Maybe: Are you coming from a C mindset where you would have to account for the null terminator (then forgot that consideration in your loops)?

As @user12002570 says you are not using standard C++, when compiling your code make sure you enable ALL warnings as shown here.  And you will get an error like this warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr'

not sure if this is what you need, check this,
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Write your main here
    string inputOne = "";
    string inputTwo = "";

    cout << "Please enter two positive integers up to 20 digits long" << endl;
    cin >> inputOne;
    cin >> inputTwo;

    int* arrOne = new int[inputOne.length()];
    int* arrTwo = new int[inputTwo.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i< inputOne.length(); i++){
        arrOne[i] = inputOne[i] - '0';
        cout<< "arrOne[i] = " << arrOne[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< inputTwo.length(); i++){
        arrTwo[i] = inputTwo[i] - '0';
        cout<< "arrTwo[i] = " << arrTwo[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< inputOne.length(); i++){
        cout<< "arrOne[i] = " << arrOne[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] arrOne;
    delete[] arrTwo;

    return 0;
   }

the output i get from g++ would be;
Please enter two positive integers up to 20 digits long
12345
0
arrOne[i] = 1
arrOne[i] = 2
arrOne[i] = 3
arrOne[i] = 4
arrOne[i] = 5
arrTwo[i] = 0
arrOne[i] = 1
arrOne[i] = 2
arrOne[i] = 3
arrOne[i] = 4
arrOne[i] = 5

your code output was;
Please enter two positive integers up to 20 digits long
12345
0
arrOne[i] = 1
arrOne[i] = 2
arrOne[i] = 3
arrOne[i] = 4
arrOne[i] = 5
arrTwo[i] = 0
arrOne[i] = 0
arrOne[i] = 2
arrOne[i] = 3
arrOne[i] = 4
arrOne[i] = 5


I initialized the arrays to one shorter value than I should have hence the odd behavior.  Appreciate the quick reply.

Better to make those dynamically allocated arrays vectors. Then you can populate them with std::transform. E.g. `std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](auto ch) { return ch - '0'; });
